# the value of 'this' inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a program as :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   this.name = "John";
   var someFunc = function()
   {
     return this.name;
   }
});
```

From my understanding , the value of '**this**' in `someFunc` is "window" since it is not contained in any object.

My question is why is the value of '`this`' is '`HtmlDocument`' in `$(document).ready(function() { alert(this) }`?

And since `someFunc` is under `$(document).ready` function why cant its value not be '`HtmlDocument`' as well ? 
Whats exactly happening behind the scene which is causing the value of this to be different in different cases?

Comment: Value of `this` is determined by how function is called. If method is being called without any context, `this` refers to window..

Comment: To answer your first question, in jQuery, `this` context in handler/callback function refers to element on which method is invoked hence `document` is being held by `this`

Comment: Read <a href="https://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified">this</a> (https://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified) for example for a short overview of 'this' in java script:

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Answer (score 2):

The variable `this` has a concept of scope in JavaScript, its value depends on where you're accessing to it, I'd try to explain this with an example, see following code snippet:

```js
$("#document").ready(function() {
  console.log("HERE 'this' references to its owner object \"HTMLDocument\"");
  console.log(this.toString());
  jsFunction();
  $("#test").jqueryFunction();
  console.log("You could call jsFunction on window:");
  window.jsFunction();
  console.log("But you can't call jqueryFunction on window:");
  try{
    window.jqueryFunction();
  }catch(err){console.log("error");}
  console.log("Neither you could call jsFunction on \"div test\":");
  try{
    $("#test").jsFunction();
  }catch(err){console.log("error");}
  
  //Inner functions
  console.log("The same thing applies to inner functions");
  var innerFunc = function(){
    console.log(this.toString());
    
    var moreInnerFunc = function(){
      console.log(this.toString());
    }
    moreInnerFunc();
  }
  innerFunc();
  
  (function(){
    console.log("Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)");
    console.log(this.toString());
  })();
  
  var extDeclared = externallyDeclared;
  extDeclared();
  $("#document").extDeclared();
});

function jsFunction(){
  console.log("HERE 'this' references to its owner \"window\"");
  console.log(this.toString());
}

(function( $ ){
 $.fn.jqueryFunction = function() {
    console.log("HERE 'this' references to its owner \"div test\"");
    console.log($(this).prop("id"));
 }; 
})( jQuery );

function externallyDeclared(){
  console.log("externallyDeclared may be window or its other owner");
  console.log(this.toString());
}

(function( $ ){
 $.fn.extDeclared = externallyDeclared;
})( jQuery );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" />
```

As you can see, `this` references always to its "owner" object, so when you declare a function outside any kind of object, its owner is the `window` object, otherwise it references to the object where the function is defined.

**In summary:**

```
function externallyDeclared(){
  console.log("externallyDeclared may be window or its other owner");
  console.log(this.toString());
}

(function( $ ){
 $.fn.extDeclared = externallyDeclared;
})( jQuery );

$("document").ready(function(){
    var extDeclared = externallyDeclared;
    extDeclared(); //<-- "no owner" - this=window
    $("#document").extDeclared(); //<-- "has an owner" - this=its owner
});
```

I hope I was clear, bye.